# How to properly compile source to output into a library and com/ directory?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to create a plugin that compiles source into a jar as well as the com/ directory.

My build.properties contains:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               plugin.properties,\
               .
jars.compile.order = myDir/myJar.jar
source.myDir/myJar.jar = src/
output.myDir/myJar.jar = bin/
source.. = src/
```

And the manifest contains:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: myDir/myJar.jar, .
```

It seems to output as expected. But I'm not 100% sure this is right since I get a warning stating: The folders 'src/' share the same output folder but are targeted for different libraries in the build.properties.

Comment: It is saying that all the code in the `src` folder will be compiled in to both the jar and the bin directory. You don't appear to be including the jar in the bin.includes so it won't be in the built plugin - so why specify it in the Bundle-Classpath? Perhaps you should [edit] your question and explain why you are trying to do this.

Comment: @greg-449 I'd like to compile into a specific jar for analysis purposes